# How to call the controller with a javascript function reacting on ClientSideEvents.DateChanged

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

My ASP.net MVC Application contains a DevExpress DateEdit extension, with that Im able to choose the date (http://mvc.devexpress.com/Editors/DateEdit), now I like to send, every time the user changes the date, the date back to the controller by reacting on the handler of my DateEdit extension.

I set ClientSideEvents.DateChanged on a javascript function and now my questions starts, usually I send data with a form and a submit back to the controller and the binder binds them to my model...

but now I would like to call in the javascript function a method on my controller like writeDate(DateTime date), a ActionLink would probably do the trick, because I know that it is possible to call the controller by a link like "\myController\Method\Parameters", but I do not know how to realize that without an action of the user.

My Code:

```
@Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "Date";
                        settings.Properties.UseMaskBehavior = true;
                        settings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                        settings.Properties.EditFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                        settings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                        settings.Date = DateTime.Now;
                        settings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DateChanged = "OnDateChanged";
                    }).GetHtml()
                @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings => {
                    settings.Name = "sendDate";
                    settings.ClientVisible = false;
                    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
                });

function OnDateChanged(s, e) {
    // Call Controller
}

[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult onDateChanged(DateTime date)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

So I think my general question is how do I pass data to the controller without a form and only by reacting on a client side event ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If devexpress can call a js function as a result of a client-side event then you can do this:

```
function OnDateChanged(s, e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("onDateChanged","Controller_Name")',
        type: 'POST',
        // e here depends on how devexpress pass the value
        // e.Value? or e.val(), just replace it accordingly
        data: { date: e }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this, is to use the CallbackPanel extension from devexpress, adding the DateTime extension into the content of it, setting the CallBackRouteValues of the panel to the controller, reacting on the ClientSideEvent of the DateTime-Extension and trigger there the callback to the server.

View

```
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    var date = null;
    function OnDateChanged(s, e) {
        date = Datum.GetValue();
        if (!CBPDateEdit.InCallback()) {
            CBPDateEdit.PerformCallback();
        }
    }

    function OnBeginCallback(s, e) {
        e.customArgs["newDate"] = Date.GetValue().toString();
    }
    </script>
@Html.DevExpress().CallbackPanel(settings =>
{
settings.Name = "CBPDateEdit";
settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Controller", Action = "onDateChanged" };

settings.SetContent(() =>
{
    ViewContext.Writer.Write("content");
    Html.DevExpress().DateEdit(DateSettings =>
                    {
                        DateSettings.Name = "Date";
                        DateSettings.Properties.UseMaskBehavior = true;
                        DateSettings.Properties.EditFormat = EditFormat.Custom;
                        DateSettings.Properties.EditFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                        DateSettings.Properties.DisplayFormatString = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
                        DateSettings.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
                        DateSettings.Date = DateTime.Now;
                        DateSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.DateChanged = "OnDateChanged";
                    }).GetHtml();
});

settings.ClientSideEvents.BeginCallback = "OnBeginCallback";
}).GetHtml()
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult onDateChanged(String newDate)
    {

        viewModel.date= DateTime.ParseExact(newDate, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return PartialView("_CBPDateEditPartial");
    }
```